# Pivots with input

Tags: reactjs, office-ui-fabric

I have a Pivot component with 3 PivotItems.

The first 2 display just labels.  The third one displays a form input text.

[see the animated gif that shows my issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2GhDn.gif)

The problem is with Pivot 3.  When I go to any other Pivot, and then go back to Pivot 3, the value of the input text is missing.  So I guess each PivotItem is re-rendered without having persistent data.

Is this the correct behaivour?  Is there any workaround for this?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: Have you tried keeping the value of that input element in component's state?

Comment: Thanks. I have not, But I am sure I can handle it. But consider the scenario that I have many PivotIems, some showing Forms with many Fields, some with Grids with some rows to show, etc.  Would I have to keep state of everything on the parent Component?

Comment: You could keep them in an Array or Object if you are careful to properly set state (it's using a shallow check, so you'd have to make new copies of these structures every time). If you're rendering these Pivots conditionally, (that's what I assume you're doing) they will be unmounted when you change them to something else. There's also the possibility of using redux for keeping state of these inputs.

Comment: Thank you.  I will give it a try.  I just thought it could be easier, something like keeping each PivotItem on the DOM and just hiding them via styles (display:none) when inactive.

Comment: You could do that as well, it's a matter of setting either a class or just the `style` attribute in your render method.

Answer (score 0):

I agree that the correct solution would be to have a controlled TextField inside of the pivot. You pass it's current value from state on render, and onBlur(or onChange) you update state. Most form elements we recommend to use as a controlled element just displaying the current state.